# custom PHP json decoder

Tags: php, json, xml, duplicates

```
$json=
"{
"name":"John",
"name":"Karel"
}";
```

In case of use this `json_decode($json, true);` i get the `array['name']="Karel"` so after parse i get the following xml:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <name value="Karel"/>
</root>
```

I need to get this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <name>
      <element>John</element>
      <element>Karel</element>
   </name>
</root>
```

I think that i need my own json parser, i need to get `array['name']=["John","Karel"];` then i can manage to do this.

EDITS:
 I can't edit input json. I need decode from file to associative array in case of same keys i need to make an array with both values on same index.

ok whole JSONfile is this:

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "name":"Karel",
    "heslo":{"content":"Dam ten shit podle sebe"},
    "ageA":30,
    "d":21,
    "d":42,
    "ageB":30.2,
    "ageC":1,
    "ageD":0,
    "testChar":["&","<",">","\"", "'", "-"],
    "lada":{"pritelkyne":"Kristynka","plysak":"mimon", "vek":20, "oblibenýSeriál":"RobinsonůvOstrov"},
    "null":null,
    "boolT":true,
    "boolF":false,
    "cars":[ { "type": "Skoda", "number": "212 555-1234" },"Ford", "BMW",{ "type": "Hyundai", "number": "215 555-1234" }, "Fiat" ],
    "numbersSeven":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    "numbersFourteen":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
    "numbersHundredOne":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101]
}
```

but it is just one from the many examples, i need to do this generrally not exactly for this json.

So how should i do the parsing ?

Comment: it isn't about json_decode , you need to re-factor your array .

Comment: how should i refactor the array ?

Comment: i dont thin that refactoring array will work i dont have the values in array i lose them ehn im decoding from json file

Comment: To clarify, that JSON file is *invalid*, because you have the same key with two different values. If you can't change it, you need to know that most JSON parsers out there will either produce an error, or throw away part of the data (I think the spec leaves it up to the implementer what to do, but "create a new structure holding both values" is very unlikely.)

Comment: @PaulCrovella Yes, I realised that "invalid" was technically too strong a term, perhaps "extremely non-portable" would be more accurate. The RFC goes on to say "When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable." For all practical purposes, duplicate keys are A Bad Idea, because if you want something non-portable, just use a custom format native to your ecosystem of choice.

Comment: i dont care about if its valid or not, i dont creating that json files...

Comment: @ZdeněkSklenář It's useful to know that something's invalid even if you can't fix it, because you will approach the question differently: rather than asking "what option do I use to parse this JSON?", you can say "I have some slightly broken JSON, so no off-the-shelf parser is likely to help me; what can I do instead?". As Paul Crovella points out, it's technically possible that some off-the-shelf parser *will* help, but it's not worth wasting too much time looking for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use same key for different values. Instead of this you can store values in single array. Or use different array then store it in another key:

Try with following codes:

```
$json : '{"names":[{"name":"John"},{
"name":"Karel"}]
}';
```

OR

```
$json = '{"name":["John","Karel"]}';
```

**EDIT**

As edited question If you receive this input and want to change json after reeving it. You can try following code (Change json string)

```
$json=
'{
"name":"John","name":"Karel"
}';

$json =  ltrim($json,"{");
$json= rtrim($json,"}");
$tmp_arr = (array_map('trim', explode(',', $json)));
$new_arr['name']=array();
foreach ($tmp_arr as $key => $value) {
  $val = explode(':', $value);
  if(count($val)>1){
    $val=$val[1];
    $val = str_replace('"', '', $val);
    $new_arr['name'][] = $val;
  }

}

echo json_encode($new_arr); //{"name":["John","Karel"]}
```

Comment: i think that the second example will output the desired output in the question

Comment: i can't do this, i need to do in decoding.

Comment: But it will never execute same keys. It will always take last value Because last one will replace previous value

Comment: i undrestand why is hapenning but i need to save both values as i said above

Comment: ok that cold be it could you do this for every key not just 'name' ? :-)
I need to do this for whole json string generrally for every key

Comment: will you post an example?

Comment: Im getting this if i use your code
{
 "name": [
  "John",
  "Karel",
  "{content",
  "30",
  "21",
  "42",
  "30.2",
  "1",
  "0",
  "[&",
  "{pritelkyne",
  "mimon",
  "20",
  "RobinsonůvOstrov}",
  "null",
  "true",
  "false",
  "[ { type",
  " 212 555-1234 }",
  " Hyundai",
  " 215 555-1234 }",
  "[1",
  "[1",
  "[1"
 ]
}

Comment: its really good idea to edit the string before decoding, but i dont know how to edit this right :-(

Answer (score 0):

try to use jsonarray : it would look like [ {"name":"John"},
{"name":"Karel"} ]
so try this

```
$arraysforjson = array();
$arraysforjson [] = array('name' => "$name")
$json = json_encode($d);
```

Comment: i need decode not encode and i need key that is in my json file i dont have only name as keys, this is just snipped json